# Apache keeps issuing a self-signed certificate even after installing a certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have purchased and installed an SSL certificate on my apache server. The problem is the server is still serving a self-signed certificate.

Comment: This question does not provide any useful information. There are many Apache installations out there which don't exhibit the behavior you describe. It is impossible due to lack of absolutely any details to find out why your installation behaves differently. Likely you did something wrong - but since you even provide details on what you did it is unclear what exactly you did wrong.

Comment: All I was, modify the httpd-ssl.config file ot point to the CA, crt and key. That's all.

Comment: Which narrows the problem down a little bit to either making errors while modifying the file or modifying the wrong file or forgetting to modify other files - but there are still not sufficient information of what you actually did and of how the configuration looks like vs. of how it is supposed to look like.

Comment: What OS are you using? What type of Apache installation are you using, for example: XAMPP, apache2 package from apt, etc...? I assume you are using XAMPP, or I atleast think you are using Windows. We need more info to assist you. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My server is CentOs7 with apache as webServer